# Is there an HtmlEditor for C# Winforms that supports right-to-left languages?

Tags: c#, winforms, right-to-left, html-editor

Is there is any HtmlEditor in C# winforms that supports right-to-left languages?
I have an application in c# that controls content of a website, and I need to have an htmlEditor. This website is in Persian.

Answer (score 0):

Hadi, since I don't know what do you mean by saying HtmlEditor and what technology are you using, I will vote for Telerik RadEditor in case you are on the .Net platform and in case this is what you need:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/righttoleft/defaultcs.aspx

Note that the Telerik RadEditor is bound to the .Net platform and can't be used in a PHP page for example.

**Update** Now I've found that the CKEditor also supports RTL:

http://ckeditor.com/demo find the right to left button and click it (it's on the second line of toolbars, somewhere in the middle).

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I want this in winform application, c#.net win application. but, the telerik will used in asp.net pages, and ckeditor in a web page. thanks again

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand you. Can you please confirm if you have found the solution to your answer or not yet? If you are using some HTML Editor you have found for Windows Application, can you please share it with us?

Thanks!